# what is unit of time in kstat time

Tags: solaris

I am using kstat to get read time and write time for a partition.

```
kstat -T u -p -c partition
```

### sample output:

```
  sd:1:sd1,r:class  partition  
  sd:1:sd1,r:crtime 190.732758214  
  sd:1:sd1,r:nread  0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:nwritten   0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:rcnt   0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:reads  0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:rlastupdate    0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:rlentime   0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:rtime  0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:snaptime   171720.447123515  
  sd:1:sd1,r:wcnt   0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:wlastupdate    0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:wlentime   0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:writes 0  
  sd:1:sd1,r:wtime  0
```

I am taking rtime and wtime from the output of above command.
But, what is the time unit of this time? I read the man page, but it doesn't elaborate.

Comment: Check the kstat(3KSTAT) man page, as it discusses the structs in question. Looks like 64-bit nanosec values.

Answer (score 0):

`crtime` (kstat creation time) and `snaptime` (last data snapshot time) are of type `hrtime_t` which represent nanoseconds.

See the [kstat manual page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1468/kstat-3kstat.html) for details.